# Do not see changes in DataContext of DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I set the DataContext of a particular row in a WPF DataGrid to a different object. The DataContext is changed (seen in the Watch window), but the various bound columns don't reflect the changed DataContext for that row.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnDataContextChange_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnDataContextChange.Click
    Dim row = dtgChildren.FindVisualChild(Of DataGridRow)()
    row.DataContext = DBEntities.Persons.Single(Function(x) x.PersonID = 22)
End Sub
```

How can I force a refresh of the bindings?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? I'm pretty sure *that* is not how you are supposed to do it.

Comment: @Sheridan That **is** what he's trying to do -- change the DataContext of a DataGrid row, and have the bound columns reflect the changed DataContext.

Comment: I don't think this will work because a DataGrid manages the `DataContext` for each `DataGridRow`. Instead you need to replace the appropriate item in the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`, and it will be reflected in the grid. For example, `MyItems[DataGrid.SelectedIndex] = new Person(...)` where `MyItems` is an `ObservableCollection`, and `DataGrid.ItemsSource` is bound to `MyItems`